# How to get user path with NSURL

Tags: swift, macos, nsurl

I'm trying to find the Swift equivalent of `~/`.

So, I want to create an NSURL with the user path. I've looked at `NSURLComponents`, but I can't see anything there. The `user` var seems only to apply to existing URLs. I'm sure this is pretty basic, but haven't found anything.

Comment: Do you mean the documents folder or the folder named after the user?

Comment: The folder named after the user. I can use `appendingPathComponents` to add Desktop, Documents or other sub-folders.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the home directory in Swift you just need to use the following:

```
let homeDirectory = NSHomeDirectory()
```

This will print out:

```
/Users/FOLDER_NAMED_AFTER_USER
```

Comment: I knew it would be something easy! Many thanks.

Comment: Np glad to help, good luck with your project @benwiggy